# Rails carrierwave make contain image in square and fill remaining area with white space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, carrierwave

While using carrier wave with rails, is it possible to take an image such as a bookcover which has a greater height than width, and resize_to_fill it such that I will end up with a square image where the book cover is centered and the remaining space on the left and right is either whitespace or transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is something along the lines of

```
process resize_and_pad : [200,100,"#000000",Magick::CenterGravity]
```

as mentioned in [RMagick docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.10.0/CarrierWave/RMagick)